# Hyperledger Fabric installChaincode error Missing peer objects in install chaincode request

Tags: node.js, installation, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to install a chaincode to a blockchain environment by using the [installChaincode hyperledger fabric node sdk function](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html#installChaincode__anchor) via a node bridge. The way I'm calling the function is as follows :

```
let fabricClient = new FabricClient();
...
let request = {
                targets: ['peer0-Org1'],
                chaincodePath: '[path_to_chaincode]',
                chaincodeId: 'abcd',
                chaincodeVersion: 'v1.0',
            }


let result = await fabricClient.installChaincode({
                request: request,
                timeout: 5000
            });
```

However, I'm getting an error that says I am `Missing peer objects in install chaincode request`.

The full error message is:
`error: [Client.js]: installChaincode error Missing peer objects in install chaincode request`

What could I've missed in setting up the request object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was calling the function wrong,

```
let result = await fabricClient.installChaincode(request, 5000);
```